# Restriction vs. multiplication by $n$ in Tate cohomology

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cor}{Cor}$
Let $H$ be a subgroup of index $n$ of a finite group $G$, and let $M$ be a $G$-module,
that is, an abelian group on which $G$ acts.
Consider  the restriction and corestriction homomorphisms in Tate cohomology:
\begin{align*}
\Res\colon\, &H^{-1}(G,M) \to H^{-1}(H,M),\\
\Cor\colon\, &H^{-1}(H,M) \to H^{-1}(G,M).
\end{align*}
Since
$$ \Cor \circ \Res =n,$$
we know that for $\xi \in H^{-1}(G, M)$,
$$\text{if}\  \, \Res \xi=0,\ \text{then}\ \,  n\xi=0.$$

> **Question:**
> What is an example of $(G,H,M,\xi)$ such that
> $$n\xi=0,\ \ \text{but}\ \  \Res \xi \neq 0\ ?$$